# undefined method `user_url' for Devise SessionsController:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have user model for authorization with devise gem. I want to add after_sign_in_path method:

```html
# application_controller.rb

protected
# redirecting to appropriate url based on role
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if current_user.has_role?(:admin)
      dashboard_path
    elsif current_user.has_role?(:student)
      root_path
    end
  end
```

Whenever I try to sign in I get this error:

```html
undefined method `user_url' for #<Devise::SessionsController:0x007fb89b5b00a8> Did you mean? course_url
```

I don't know why it says 'did you mean? course_url. But I have course model. And here are my routes:

```html
authenticate :user do

    resources :feeds, only: [:index]
    resources :courses, only: [:index, :show]    
    # etc...

  end
```

Also here is the code it points me:

```html
if options.empty?
            recipient.send(method, *args)
  else
            recipient.send(method, *args, options)
  end
```

and first line of log:

```html
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:220:in `polymorphic_method'
```

Whenever I commend after_sign_in_path_for I am able to sign in. If I comment contents of after_sign_in_path_for but leave empty after_sign_in_path_for method, I also get this error.

EDIT: I tested that I am not also signed in, not just not redirected. I think error happens right in the call after_sign_in_path_for, not in the redirect_to or whatever. Probably it has to do something with resource.

EDIT2: here are my rake routes:

```html
  new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)         devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)     devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)    devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)           registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                  registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)          registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)             registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                  registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                  registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                  registrations#destroy
       user_confirmation POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)     devise/confirmations#create
   new_user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format) devise/confirmations#new
                         GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)     devise/confirmations#show
              admin_root GET    /                                 rails_admin/main#dashboard
            student_root GET    /                                 feeds#index
                   feeds GET    /feeds(.:format)                  feeds#index
                 courses GET    /courses(.:format)                courses#index
                  course GET    /courses/:id(.:format)            courses#show
                 schools GET    /schools(.:format)                schools#index
                  school GET    /schools/:id(.:format)            schools#show
            universities GET    /universities(.:format)           universities#index
              university GET    /universities/:id(.:format)       universities#show
             rails_admin        /admin                            RailsAdmin::Engine
                         POST   /graphql(.:format)                graphql#create
    landing_confirmation GET    /landing/confirmation(.:format)   landing#confirmation
   landing_access_denied GET    /landing/access_denied(.:format)  landing#access_denied
                    root GET    /                                 landing#index
```

EDIT3: here is my github repo:

```html
https://github.com/yerassyl/nurate
```

Comment: Are you able to  get current_user in after_sign_in ?

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma, even if i comment contents of after_sign_in_path_for, I get this error.

Comment: remove the contents of method & write logger.info("current_user="+current_user.to_json)super  , what is the output you get after this

Comment: At first look, your routes doesn't look standard. I mean the way that devise suggested it. You should check the devise gem doc. Personally I would configure a classic devise routes and authenticate in controller with a before action.

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma, undefined method `super' for true:TrueClass Did you mean? suppress. or if I remove .super I got: undefined method `to_model' for true:TrueClass Did you mean? to_yaml

Comment: @yerassyl :Do u get current_user in the log like current_user = {}

Comment: @codingaddicted, yeah, but I always do this way. And it works.

Comment: That's what I thought ;) Can you include the output of a rake routes?

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma, I couldn't log current use. But doing current_user.present? indicates me that current_user is defined

Comment: Paste your complete application controller code & complete log

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma, I posted github repo. also I have nothing in my controllers yet. just scaffolds. I was integrating devise, cancancan first.

Comment: ok, Where is your after_sign_in method?

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma, application_controller, it is protected

Comment: I don't see this method in the git url & this should be public

Comment: after_sign_in redirect admin user to dashboard path but you don't have one, you have an admin_root_path you can use.

Comment: @codingaddicted, by the way, I have this routes, I just didn't posted them, as I thought they are not related. They come from rails_admin gem

Comment: @yerassyl, ok I keep digging ;)

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma, I will push my code now under metronic_integration branch, and I worked for me as protected before.

Comment: okk, no problem with the protected , push your code now

Comment: have you restarted the sever after setting after_sign_in path

Comment: @kajalojha, yep, many times.

Answer (score 48):

I had the same issue (Rails 7). I fixed it this way:

Add :turbo_stream as a navigational format. This line goes in config/initializers/devise.rb.

```
config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html, :turbo_stream]
```

[Devise issue github](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/issues/5439)

Answer (score 5):

This error is thrown when the `after_sign_in_path_for` method is redefined in your app and returns `nil` value. As per my best guest, the provided snippet

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if current_user.has_role?(:admin)
    dashboard_path
  elsif current_user.has_role?(:student)
    root_path
 end
end
```

is giving an error because none of the conditions are getting satisfied and hence the returned value is `nil`. To avoid such a case, you can always add an `else` condition which would get satisfied if no other does. Hence the below snippet should have worked (and will work for other users)

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  if current_user.has_role?(:admin)
    dashboard_path
  elsif current_user.has_role?(:student)
    root_path
  else
   some_other_path || root_path
  end
end
```

Hope this helps someone. Cheers :)

Answer (score 4):

In config/devise.rb include this line:

```
config.navigational_formats = ['/', :html, :turbo_stream]
```

before rails s

This has done the trick for me.

Comment: Thanks. Doing `config.navigational_formats = ['*/*, :html'] was enough for me. It's worth to mention that I just kicked off a new project and haven't started implementing Hotwire yet.

Answer (score 3):

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
 if current_user.has_role?(:admin)
  dashboard_path
 elsif current_user.has_role?(:student)
  root_path
 else
  root_path
 end
end
```

Try to add a else condition in your code. This worked for me. I missed something like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same error with Devise::RegistrationsController, the answers of Jishnu and antoniolulee also works fine.

You have to uncomment in config/initializers/devise.rb line says

```
config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html]
```

and add :turbo_stream like this

```
config.navigational_formats = ['*/*', :html, :turbo_stream]
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you've got a method on your `AplicationController` like follows

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  resource.next_step
end
```

`Next_step` is an attribute stored in the record during its creation, you may decide to hard code here some other path.